# How to modify Request body in a WCF Data Service

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

I have a WCF Data Service and when a new object is sent for saving by the client, I get a Deserialization error, as the *body contains invalid data*:

```
An error occurred while processing this request.
   at: System.Data.Services.Serializers.ODataMessageReaderDeserializer.Deserialize(SegmentInfo segmentInfo)
   at: System.Data.Services.Serializers.Deserializer.ReadEntity(ResourceType& entityTypeInPayload)
   at: System.Data.Services.Serializers.Deserializer.HandlePostRequest(ResourceType& targetResourceType)
   at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandlePostOperation(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)
   at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessIncomingRequest(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)
   at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description)
   at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()

Inner Exception: Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Int32'. See the inner exception for more details.
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.ConvertStringToPrimitive(String text, IEdmPrimitiveTypeReference targetTypeReference)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.ReadPrimitiveValue(XmlReader reader, IEdmPrimitiveTypeReference primitiveTypeReference)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ReadNonEntityValueImplementation(IEdmTypeReference expectedTypeReference, DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, CollectionWithoutExpectedTypeValidator collectionValidator, Boolean validateNullValue, Boolean epmPresent, String propertyName)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ReadProperty(String expectedPropertyName, IEdmTypeReference expectedPropertyTypeReference, ODataNullValueBehaviorKind nullValueReadBehaviorKind, Boolean epmPresent)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomPropertyAndValueDeserializer.ReadPropertiesImplementation(IEdmStructuredType structuredType, ReadOnlyEnumerable`1 properties, DuplicatePropertyNamesChecker duplicatePropertyNamesChecker, Boolean epmPresent)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadAtomContentElement(IODataAtomReaderEntryState entryState)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadAtomElementInEntry(IODataAtomReaderEntryState entryState)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomEntryAndFeedDeserializer.ReadEntryContent(IODataAtomReaderEntryState entryState)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.Atom.ODataAtomReader.ReadAtEntryStartImplementation()
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadImplementation()
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.ReadSynchronously()
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.InterceptException[T](Func`1 action)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.ODataReaderCore.Read()
   at: System.Data.Services.Serializers.EntityDeserializer.ReadEntry(ODataReader odataReader, SegmentInfo topLevelSegmentInfo)
   at: System.Data.Services.Serializers.EntityDeserializer.Read(SegmentInfo segmentInfo)
   at: System.Data.Services.Serializers.ODataMessageReaderDeserializer.Deserialize(SegmentInfo segmentInfo)

Inner Exception: Input string had an incorrect format.
   at: System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at: System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at: Microsoft.Data.OData.AtomValueUtils.ConvertStringToPrimitive(String text, IEdmPrimitiveTypeReference targetTypeReference)

   at: System.Data.Services.Serializers.ODataMessageReaderDeserializer.Deserialize(SegmentInfo segmentInfo)
   at: System.Data.Services.Serializers.Deserializer.ReadEntity(ResourceType& entityTypeInPayload)
   at: System.Data.Services.Serializers.Deserializer.HandlePostRequest(ResourceType& targetResourceType)
   at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandlePostOperation(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)
   at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.ProcessIncomingRequest(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)
   at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleNonBatchRequest(RequestDescription description)
   at: System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
```

Can I modify the request body on the server side to avoid this error?

Comment: from the inner exceptions, I saw `Input string had an incorrect format` and `Cannot convert a primitive value to the expected type 'Edm.Int32'`. Debug to see what's there instead of a `int`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh There is a `string` value there. I should replace the `string` with an `int` there, that's why I have to modify the request body.

Comment: If you can implement a custom parameter inspector, it'd be easy.

Comment: I guess, WCF Parameter Inspector applies only to WCF and not WCF Data Services, according to this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733747%28v=vs.110%29.aspx